how to get source code of contract deployed by evm
I copy and pasted together a very basic contract in 2018 devoid of functionality, someone from the EVM department added what was needed and deployed the contract, I would like to take the contract off of the EVM and have control of the content within, I will have to hire someone because I personally don't have the skills to do it (any suggestions welcome). Can you help me to get the source code I would need to make this happen?
